# Redirecting input using stdin

Tags: c++, sorting, stdin

I am writing a short program to sort an array of integers. I am having trouble opening my input file which is "prog1.d". The assignment has asked to create a symbolic link in the programs directory, and I after creating the object & executable, we invoke the program as follows...

```
prog1.exe < prog1.d &> prog1.out
```

I know my bubble sort works correctly & efficiently because I have used my own test 'txt' file.

The assignment says:

> Your program gets the random integers from stdin and puts them in an array, sorts the integers in the array in ascending order, and then displays the contents of the array on stdout.

How do I read the file using 'cin' until EOF & add the integers to my array a[] ?

Here is my code so far:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int a[SIZE];

    for ( int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        ifstream inFile; // declare stream
        inFile.open( argv[i] ); // open file
        // if file fails to open...
        if( inFile.fail() )
        {
            cout << "The file has failed to open";
            exit(-1);
        }
        // read int's & place into array a[]
        for(int i=0; !inFile.eof(); i++)
        {
            inFile >> a[i];
        }
        inFile.close(); // close file
    }

    bubbleSort(a); // call sort routine
    printArr(a); // call print routine

    return 0;
}
```

I know that opening a stream is the wrong way to do this, I just was using it for a test 'txt' file I was using to make sure my sorting worked. The teacher said we should redirect the input to 'cin' like someone was entering integers on a keyboard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your bubblesort works efficiently?  That's a contradiction.

Comment: lol, nice. I meant its working as intended. better?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: There are rare cases in witch a well implemented bubble sort outdoes all other usual sorting algorithms.

Comment: @Nobody: Are you referring to the cocktail sort or comb sort?  Because those are not the bubble sort anymore.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Nope. I am talking about bubblesort implementations that will have a average case complexity of O(n²) but can run in O(n) in special cases where quicksort and others would need O(n log n). One such special case would be a sorted sequence or a sequence where each second element swapped position with its predecessor.

Comment: @Nobody: I misunderstood and thought the emphasis was on `well implemented` rather than `rare cases`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using redirection on the command line, `argv` does not contain the redirection. Instead, the specified file simply becomes your `stdin`/`cin`. So you don't need to (and shouldn't try to) open it explicitly -- just read from the standard input, as you would read from the terminal when input isn't redirected.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are piping the file on the stdin, you don't have the file name on argv[1], just read the stdin as the user was typing at the console, for example using `cin`:

```
cin.getline (...);
```

Comment: +1, right up until you mentioned `gets()`, which deserves a -1.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example? I am basically asking how to read the input from an entire file as if they were typing at the console

Comment: @Oli fixed, I misunderstood was c not c++

Comment: @bluetickk, use _the exact same code_ as you would write for reading from the console. That's the beauty of i/o redirection: Your program doesn't even know whether it's reading from a file or from the console.

Comment: @Felice: Even in C, you should not be using `gets()`!  But anyway, -1 removed.

Comment: @henning Makholm how do i iterate through the values though?

Comment: @bluetickk, with the code you already have following the `read int's & place into array a[]` comment. Just use `cin` instead of `inFile`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are completely correct, but here's the rewritten code to claify:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int a[SIZE];
    int count = 0;

    // read int's & place into array a[]
    //ALWAYS check the boundries of arrays
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) 
    {
        std::cin >> a[i];
        if (std::cin)
            count = count + 1;
        else
            break;
    }

    bubbleSort(a, count); // call sort routine
    printArr(a, count); // call print routine

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `std::ios::eof` to test for end of input. It is easier and more reliable to test the bool value of the `>>` expression.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/79dyq or http://ideone.com/FH6xQ for examples of why `std::ios::eof` is evil.

Comment: Corrected.  I usually try to correct samples with minimal changes, which is why I left that part origionally.

Comment: The bug in those samples has nothing to do with eof, and everything to do with checking the state of the stream in the incorrect location.  Although I admit that's an incredibly common mistake with istreams.

Comment: I disagree. Regardless of where you put `eof()`, you're going to have a bug. Consider: http://ideone.com/1Obb8 and http://ideone.com/UAzAa.

Comment: I admit to being surprised by that second example, I expected that to work.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has stated, use `std::cin` directly -- you don't need to open the input file, your shell has already done that for you.

But, please, please, please, don't use `cin.eof()` to test to see if you have reached the end of your input. If your input is flawed, your program will hang. Even if your input isn't flawed, your program may (but won't necessarily) run the loop one extra time.

Try this loop instead:

```
int a[SIZE];
int i = 0;
while( std::cin >> a[i]) {
  ++i;
}
```

Or, add robustness by using `std::vector` which will automatically grow:

```
std::vector<int> a;
int i;
while(std::cin >> i) {
  a.push_back(i);
}
```

Or, use generic algorithms:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
...
std::vector<int> a;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(a));
```